# React rendering display wrong elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting to learn React with a to-do list mini project. It has three Components:

- `Tasks` is the main component (child of `App`). It render a `NewTask` component which add new tasks and contains an array with all of the `Task` components to show.
- `NewTask` is an `input` to add a new `Task` to the list.
- `Task` represent a task

My goal is to add a new `Task` into the top of the list, so I have thought that the best way to do this is to add the `Task` to the start of the array of `Tasks`. Here is the problem, when I do this the render doesn't display the tasks correctly, and repeat the last one. When I add the task to the last element the render results are correct. Here some pictures:

[image]
[image]

*(At the left not correct and at the right correct)*

Here is the code of the three components:

```js
class Tasks extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           tasks: [<Task text="Comprar cerveza"/>, 
                   <Task text="Hacer la comida"/>, 
                   <Task text="Ver HIMYM"/>,
                   <Task text="Escuchar nuevo disco"/>]
        }
    }

    addNewTask = (text) => {
        // this.setState({tasks: this.state.tasks.concat(<Task text={text}/>)}) // Add to bottom 
        this.setState({tasks: [<Task text={text}/>].concat(this.state.tasks)}) // Add to top
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="task-container">
                <NewTask parentMethod={this.addNewTask} text="New Task"/>
                {this.state.tasks}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```js
class NewTask extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        if(event.key === 'Enter'){
            this.props.parentMethod(event.target.value);
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="task">
                <input className="new-task" placeholder={this.props.text} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```js
class Task extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           completed: false
        }
    }

    changeState(){
        this.setState({completed: !this.state.completed});
    }

    render(){
        let class_button = "check-button " + (this.state.completed ? 'completed' : 'not-completed');
        let class_text = "posted-task " + (this.state.completed ? 'completed' : 'not-completed');

        return (
            <div className="task">
                <button className={class_button} onClick={this.changeState.bind(this)}/>
                <input className={class_text} defaultValue={this.props.text}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead to add to the top:

```
addNewTask = (text) => {
            this.setState(prevstate => {tasks: [<Task text={text}/>, ...prevState.tasks]
        }
```

this is a less error prone of updating an array in the state.

Also its not really a good idea to have something like this:

```
this.state = {
           tasks: [<Task text="Comprar cerveza"/>, 
                   <Task text="Hacer la comida"/>, 
                   <Task text="Ver HIMYM"/>,
                   <Task text="Escuchar nuevo disco"/>]
}
```

What you should have is something like this:

```
    this.state = {
               tasks: ["Comprar cerveza", "Hacer la comida", "Ver 
    HIMYM","Escuchar nuevo disco"] 
}
```

And you would render that like this:

```
{this.state.tasks.map((task, index) => <Task text={task} key={`${index}.${task}`}/>}
```

Comment: That's not work for me. Could you explain the statement?

Comment: I noticed that I had a warning about the keys, so I assign a unique key to each element as you did. I didn't know nothing about keys when I posted the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't come by the way how I added the new element to the array. The problem was that if I don't specify a unique key for each element, React detect it as the same component and it won't be rendered again. The new component looks like:

```
class Tasks extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: [0,1,2,3],
            tasks: ["Comprar cerveza", 
                    "Hacer la comida", 
                    "Ver HIMYM",
                    "Escuchar nuevo disco"]
        }
    }

    addNewTask = (text) => {
        // Add to top
        this.setState({ id: [this.state.id.length].concat(this.state.id),
                        tasks: [text].concat(this.state.tasks)})
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="task-container">
                <NewTask parentMethod={this.addNewTask} text="New Task"/>
                {/* Create the task */}
                {this.state.tasks.map( (el,i) => {
                    return(
                        <Task id={this.state.id[i]} text={el}/>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
class Task extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           completed: false
        }
    }

    changeState(){
        this.setState({completed: !this.state.completed});
    }

    render(){
        let class_button = "check-button " + (this.state.completed ? 'completed' : 'not-completed');
        let class_text = "posted-task " + (this.state.completed ? 'completed' : 'not-completed');

        return (
            <div className="task" key={this.props.id}>
                <button className={class_button} onClick={this.changeState.bind(this)}/>
                <input className={class_text} defaultValue={this.props.text}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```